# Opencv error on ARM

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, static-libraries

I hope someone can help me. I have a c++ file which use opencv libraries.
I need to get an executable for an ARM in which I have to run it. My executable should be compile in a static linker way.

I am not an exepert so sorry If I am doing something weird, I follow this steps:

I download the opencv for ARM libraries, I build it with the cmake and I got the statics opencv ARM libraries without problems.

Then I try to compile my c++ file like this:

```
 arm-linux-g++ -static -o exampleWindows IPCamera.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

And it works, so I got an executable, I write:

```
 file executable
```

And I get this output:

```
  ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux    2.6.26, not stripped
```

So it seems that is ok, is an ARM format and is a static linked. But when I try to run this executable in my ARM is comming this error:

```
 OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. 
 Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. 
 If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, 
 then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, 
 file /home/jesus/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 483
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/jesus/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483: error: (-2)    The function is not implemented.
 Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or   Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, 
 then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow
```

Then how I am not an expert I tried to follow what the error message says, so I donwload the libgtk2.0 in my ubuntu, and then I make again the cmake and make for build the ARM static libraries, but nothing is solved.

So I need some help with this error, or tell what is the meaning, because it seem that is simple but I do not know what to do.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
 cout<<"ready"<<endl;
 cv::Mat frame;

 cv::namedWindow("front", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
 cvMoveWindow("front", 0, 0);
 cvSetWindowProperty( "front", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

 return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much I hope someon could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to rebuild OpenCV **with the GTK-support activated**. The necessary steps are:

1. Install gtk (`sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`, I think you did this already ;) ).
2. Rebuild OpenCV:

   - If you installed it from the repositories, re-install it (I think this is not the case).
   - If you manually built OpenCV from source code: run cmake with it again, **making sure that the option WITH_GTK is marked** (you can use the CMAKE GUI to activate that option).

   Once the Makefiles have been re-generated with CMAKE, run `make`, `make install` and don't forget `ldconfig`.
3. Try again with your code ;)

Hope that it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Keill it was so clear.  I did all what you said and again the same error, I was lookin for some solution and I find that maybe I need install more libraries before the make, but I did, and I rebuold the cmake, and nothing. I check in the CmakeCache.txt and the flag WITH_GTK=ON, so I do not have idea what can be the problem. Thank you for the answer again.

Comment: I realized that once I finish to execute the Cmake in the terminal output appear

  GTK+ 2.x:                    NO

So I think this is wrong, but I do not have idea why.

Comment: You should try using `cmake-gui` to find out if cmake(opencv) is finding the gtk path correctly

Comment: Hi keill thanks for your answer. I have never use cmake-gui, where can I find that information??

Comment: On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install cmake-gui`

Comment: Hi Keill I have already the cmake-gui, How can I know if cmake is find the propertly path?I never use cmake-gui

Comment: And where should I change the Path??

Comment: Hi keill could be the problem that I have to get the gtk libraries for ARM??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that, you did not enable the GTK+ library support .
To enable it

1)install the GTK+ Libraries, if you don't have them

2) re build the libraries with including this -DWITH_GTK=ON

hope that this will work...

Answer (score 0):

1. run `ccmake .` and enable `WITH_GTK` and `WITH_GTK_2_X`
2. run `make && make install`
3. ldconfig